# Recommended ETL approachs for large to big data

Tags: sql-server, bigdata, etl

I've been reading up on this (via Google search) for a while now and still not a getting a clear answer so finally decided to post.

Am trying to get a clear idea on what is a good process for setting up automated ETL process. Let's take the following problem:

### Data:

### Product Code, Month, Year, Sales, Flag

15 million rows for data, where you had 5000 products. Given this data, calculate whether the cumulative sales for a particular product exceeds X. And set flag = 1 if at that point in time the threshold was exceeded.

How would people approach this task? My approach was to attempt it using SQL Server but that was painfully slow at times. In particular there was step in the transformation that would have required me to write a Stored Proc that created an index on a temp table on the fly on order to speed up .. all of which seemed like a lot of bother.

Should I have coded it in Java or Python? Should I have used Alteryx or Lavastorm? Is this something I should ideally be doing using Hadoop?

Comment: You could always consider using SSIS or Informatica.  I've used both in the past, and they work wonderfully for large ETL processes.  They also allow you to use stored procedures and views to push data along.  Although, based on your question, it doesn't sound like you need an ETL process.  If you're just calculating your break even (or somethig similar), what do you need to transform and load data for?  Also, is this for a school project or work or liesure? A little more info will help me out a lot in answering. Thanks!

Comment: It's for work, and I've simplified the example to make it easier to understand.  I admit I need to become better acquainted with SSIS but my understanding is that is just a drag and drop method of constructing SQL scripts? I.e. what I've created using SSMS is doing the same actions?

As for why I view this as an ETL problem, what I am trying to do will get me to stage 1, after which I can then run it through SPSS and create a prediction model.

The set up of the data has to be done once, so I consider this part of the ETL process.

Comment: SSIS can be better than SSMS for several reasons: 1. You don't need a staging area (tables) 2. SSIS does not need a SQL server to run 3. SSIS can handle multiple, advanced operations and aggregations. I totally forgot to ask you, is the data in a flat file of some sort currently or in the database? Where are you moving the data to, and where is it coming from? That's probably the first question I should have asked.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. The data is in multiple flat files and the output will go into SPSS and Tableau.

The way I see it I need to perform the following steps:

1) Calculate a running total at the Product level across 15 million rows

2) Do a look up with another table that tells me whether that running total exceeds the threshold for that product or not and then update the flag (1 = exceeds threshold)

Would step 1 run a lot quicker then if I had used SSIS as opposed to SSMS scripts?

Comment: Yes, it would be faster. Another benefit of ETL programs such as SSIS is that they can run simultaneous, parallel operations.  It sounds like you need to add a boolean flag to your tables to use in the SSIS logic so it can easily tell what it's looking for.  You also need to consider the frequency of this type of import. WIll your boss want this type of report once a week, month, quarter? If this is going to be a regular process definitely put it in an SSIS package.  If it is a one time load and transform, do it in whatever way is easiest for you.

Comment: Great looks like I need to learn to use SSIS then. It's a one off task, but I work in a busienss where the are lots one of tasks like this so looking for a good data modeling tool that process large to big datasets effectively.

Comment: I personally enjoy Informatica, but I believe the license is much pricier than SSIS.  I do recommend becoming familiar with SSIS though, it is such a powerful tool and can save you a lot of time.  You can create some packages that are very basic or generic and copy them for each new process as well. So it's not like you'll be creating vastly different packages each time.  The UI for SSIS is very straight forward as well, which makes it very easy to learn.